# Intercept WM_COMMAND (sent from an accelerator) on Internet Explorer_Server (IWebBrowser2)

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc, atl

I need to intercept the Paste message that is being sent to my CHtmlView object.  According to Spy++, it's being sent as a WM_COMMAND message - but also according to Spy++, the message isn't being sent to the CHtmlView object, but rather to the Internet Explorer_Server (or IWebBrowser2) object that it wraps.  The WM_COMMAND message in question is not seen in any other parent objects (I've found this by observation and via Spy++).

How do I intercept this (or even, say, a Select All) message?  I've watched AfxCallWndProc for the correct WM_COMMAND message, and it doesn't show up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To intercept a message (ex: WM_COMMAND) you need to subclass the window (in your case Internet Explorer_Server) by calling:

```
BOOL SetWindowSubclass(
  _In_  HWND hWnd,
  _In_  SUBCLASSPROC pfnSubclass,
  _In_  UINT_PTR uIdSubclass,
  _In_  DWORD_PTR dwRefData
);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183(v=vs.85).aspx#set_windowsubclass

After that your own windows procedure takes controls first and you can decide what to do with the message.

Comment: I ended up going with `SetWindowLongPtr()`, but this got me on the right track.  Thank you.

Comment: I used `SetWindowLongPtr()` for decades. It worked and works fine. What is wrong with `SetWindowSubclass`? It is doing just the same under the covers.